# Possible to see a list + CPU use of all user processes in a locked down Windows environment?

Tags: windows, process, security

We work in a locked down privilege environment, to the point that we are not able to see the the list of processes and CPU usage of the windows services running on one of our development servers through the Task Manager.

Is there another (command line for instance) tool that we could use on Windows Server to get a list of all processes running on the machine + CPU usage, even with the Task Manager's disabled "Show processes from all users" checkbox locked down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try Sysinternals [**Process Explorer**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

If you can get the Cygwin `cygwin1.dll` and the `ps` executable together, you might be able to do

```
ps -Wafl
```

Comment: pslist from sysinternals is also a useful one, as you can see the information of a remote computer.  pslist \\computer -s is the command you would use.